# How to check MPLS connections?

Tags: bgp, mpls, monitoring

I monitor about 150 routers with MPLS links.

To check if connection is established, I'm pinging loopbacks visible only from WAN. If a loopback is not responding, I can see which link is not working properly.

What are better possibilities? Pinging public address is not possible, as I noticed, and, sometimes, I still have router-edge router connection, but BGP is not established.

What are other monitoring options?

Comment: BFD, tracking objects, etc.

Comment: I think you need to give  abit more info. What do you wnt to check, that the WAN connection to each router is up, or that the router is up? Both? Do you just want to know if the device is alive (such as you might get with a simple ping or a bit more info, like with SNMP) ?

Comment: Also what is wrong with your current method, loopback's never go down (usually) so what about this method is not working for you? Perhaps you should be pinging the interface address instead.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "SNMP" from a network management platform (canonically Nagios, but there's a world of alternatives).

You'd be interested in monitoring:

- The BGP neighbour status of all those routers.
- The presence of all those router's loopback addresses in the BGP routing table.
- The MPLS path establishment status for each of those circuits.

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TCL inside Cisco to ping, or if the links are reachable from your PC, then you can use Python or scapy framework to ping and capture IP addresses which didn't respond.

Comment: Don't exactly understand which links i can ping: MPLS link is not responding for me every time from outerior network and my PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you are monitoring 150 routers, I would recommend implementing a network monitoring tool like Solarwinds or Nagios. Solarwinds is a commercial product with a free trail and Nagios is an Open Source solution.

Both will allow you to setup [SNMP monitoring](http://www.solarwinds.com/topics/snmp-monitoring), provide a graphical monitoring interface and allow you to configure notifications when a node goes down.

[Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/)
[Solarwinds](http://www.solarwinds.com/network-performance-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

If they are Cisco routers, have a look at [IOS Embedded Event Manager, EEM](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/ios-embedded-event-manager-eem/index.html).  You can have the router email you, for example, if a particular interface or subinterface goes down.  It is a very flexible system in terms of options.

Answer (score 0):

By using monitoring tool solarwind you will be able to get the BGP session status. And the reachability of that site, and lot more.